# Querying firebase database nested children

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, swift4

My firebase database is configured as such:

```json
{ "Posts": {
    "randomPostKey": {
      usersThatReadThisPost: {
       "randomUser":"000001",
         "anotherRandomUser":"000002"
         }
     },
     "anotherRandomPostKey": {
       usersThatReadThisPost: {
         "randomUser":"randomUserKey",
         "anotherRandomUser":"anotherRandomUserKey"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is go into every post and efficiently check if the user ("I already have the user's ID") has read the post..

I've tried querying but it doesn't really work for me...
It'll be great if someone out there can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Too broad, show us what you've tried and explain why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access `Posts`

```
private let postsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Posts")
```

Then you get all the posts and find the users inside posts

```
postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
          if let postSnapshot = child as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if let post = postSnapshot.value as? [String: Any], let usersThatReadPost = post["usersThatReadThisPost"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                       for user in userThatReadPost {
                            let values = user.values
                            for value in values  {
                               if let userId = value as? String, userId == userIdThatYouOwn {
                                 // user has read this
                                 break
                                 }
                            }
                       }
                }
          }
     }
})
```